# Super L Key Double-Triggering Whisker Menu in Xubuntu

Tags: xfce, xubuntu, xmodmap

Before upgrading to Xubuntu 22.04 I would tap the left Windows key (Super L) and it would open the Whisker menu in xfce. After upgrading, whenever I hit that same key, it is as if I typed it twice in rapid succession. I believe this is because I have something mapping that key. When I run `xev -event keyboard` I get the following for the two windows keys:

**Right Windows Key**

```
KeyPress event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x6a00001,
    root 0x1df, subw 0x0, time 484880404, (423,18), root:(1294,553),
    state 0x10, keycode 134 (keysym 0xffec, Super_R), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x6a00001,
    root 0x1df, subw 0x0, time 484880476, (423,18), root:(1294,553),
    state 0x50, keycode 134 (keysym 0xffec, Super_R), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

**Left Windows Key**

```
KeyPress event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x6a00001,
    root 0x1df, subw 0x0, time 484907025, (518,-23), root:(1389,512),
    state 0x10, keycode 133 (keysym 0xffeb, Super_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x6a00001,
    root 0x1df, subw 0x0, time 484907129, (518,-23), root:(1389,512),
    state 0x50, keycode 133 (keysym 0xffeb, Super_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

MappingNotify event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    request MappingKeyboard, first_keycode 8, count 248

KeyPress event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x6a00001,
    root 0x1df, subw 0x0, time 484907129, (518,-23), root:(1389,512),
    state 0x10, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x6a00001,
    root 0x1df, subw 0x0, time 484907130, (518,-23), root:(1389,512),
    state 0x14, keycode 9 (keysym 0xff1b, Escape), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (1b) "
mbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (1b) "
FilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x6a00001,
    root 0x1df, subw 0x0, time 484907130, (518,-23), root:(1389,512),
    state 0x14, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x6a00001,
    root 0x1df, subw 0x0, time 484907130, (518,-23), root:(1389,512),
    state 0x10, keycode 9 (keysym 0xff1b, Escape), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (1b) "
FilterEvent returns: False
```

When I run `xmodmap`, I get the following output:

```
xmodmap:  up to 4 keys per modifier, (keycodes in parentheses):

shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock        Caps_Lock (0x42)
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Alt_R (0x6c),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3      
mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
```

However, I do **not** have a `~/.Xmodmap` file. I do have a `~/.Xauthority` file, but it appears binary/opaque.

I think need to unset something via `xmodmap` (or maybe `setxkbmap`), but I'm lost as to what that would be.